# How does the "/n" switch of the "copy" command actually work on Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, filenames, copy

How does the "/n" switch of the "copy" command actually work on Windows Command Prompt?

[image: copy /?]

It seems to say that it copies the [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) instead of the [long filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename).

I tried it, but after copying, the long filename is still there, rather than an 8.3 filename.

[image: copy /n]

So how does it actually work? Is this feature broken?

Comment: It may be that it copies ***using*** the 8.3 filename, in the case that the full unicode filename contains characters that cannot easily be entered in the command prompt it may allow easier handling.

Comment: /N  :  If at all possible, create only short filenames (8.3) in the
               destination. This option can help when copying between disks
               that are formatted differently e.g NTFS and VFAT, or when archiving 
               data to an ISO9660 CDROM.

Comment: If a disk supports long file name you will get long file names **as well** as short names.

Comment: Obviously it does not copy the 8.3 filename correctly. It is 123456~2.TXT on drive D, and then it becomes 123456~1.TXT on drive A. Moreover, as you can see, drive A is a floppy disk, so it is formatted to the FAT12 file system, while drive D is formatted to the NTFS file system.